# Using jQuery's animate without using slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click_to_hide').click(function () {
        var visible = $('.hide_on_click').is(":visible");
        $('.hide_on_click').slideToggle(500);
        if (!visible) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.hide_on_click').offset().top
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to change it to use only animate, but nothing I tried worked so far.
How can I revise the code to only use animate instead of the way it is now?

Fiddle Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/YFR2e/3/

Comment: No matter which one you use, it will still become setting the `style` property to do animations. Have you tried looking into CSS animations?

Comment: You could animate the height of .hide_on_click to 0 if its visible or the actual height if its not visible.
The only drawback here is you have to know/guess the actual height for this to work.
P.S. This is exactly how slide toggle works in pure CSS.